# Complexity of Cooley Tukey FFT

Tags: computational-complexity, fast-fourier-transform

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2003354?seq=5#page_scan_tab_contents

In the original algorithm of Cooley Tukey
it says that in page 298  (11) and (12)
 the total number of operations is T(r) = rNlogN/logr.

But in many books and references it says NlogN only. 
What is the difference here?

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ might be a better candidate. This is not really about mathematics.

Comment: What is $r$ ? Usually the complexity of the FFT is the number of multiplications+additions of a certain precision.

Comment: r is the radix, here it can be 2

Answer (score 0):

Because they originally assumed the complexity of butterfly as 4 complex multiplications. They multiply all entries with complex twiddle factors.